# How to re-register common javascript events in Rails after an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm writing a Rails app which includes ajax functionality using jQuery. I hope you guys could help me out here.

For example, in my /public/javascripts/application.js :

```
/* application.js */
...

$('.item-edit').editable('/item/update', {
    name  : $(this).attr('name'),
    id   : $(this).attr('id'),
    cancel  : 'Cancel',
    submit  : 'OK',
    indicator         : 'Saving...',
    tooltip  : 'Click to edit...',
    method  :  'put',
    submitdata          :  {attribute : "name"}
  });
```

With the jEditable plugin, this code binds the registered elements for inline-editing.

So lets say I have a partial in app/views/shared/_item_info.html.erb

```
<!-- _item_info.html.erb -->
...
<li class="item-edit" id="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.name %> </li>
...
```

On first load, when any 'item-edit' elements are clicked, the user will be presented with an inline textbox with an 'Ok' button. When 'Ok' is clicked, a 'PUT' request is submitted causing that text to be saved. After that text has been saved in the DB, we will then render the new text by calling the partial:

This is what my update.js.erb looks like:

```
/* update.js.erb */
...
$("#items").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/item_info')) %>")

$('.item-edit').editable('/item/update', {
    name  : $(this).attr('name'),
    id  : $(this).attr('id'),
    cancel  : 'Cancel',
    submit  : 'OK',
    indicator : 'Saving...',
    tooltip  : 'Click to edit...',
    method  :  'put',
    submitdata  :  {attribute : "name"}
});
...
```

You may have noticed that I have to re-register my elements to enable inline-editing, if not, clicking on the elements will do nothing. My problem is that I am re-registering other events in other requests such as in create.js.erb as well which causes massive code duplication.

Is there any solutions to this problem? Is there a way where I could put all my common event re-registering codes in one .js file and include it inside a create.js.erb, update.js.erb...so that all my events will be re-registered without me having to copy/paste code?

Sorry for being long-winded. Would appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides an awesome method to do this called .live  (docs: http://api.jquery.com/live/ )

However since your using a plugin and calling .editable to do the binding, you would have to modify the source of jEditable to use .live appropriately, which may (or may not) be more work than its worth.

There actually seems to be some other very similar questions:

[jeditable live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343109/jeditable-live)

[Making JEditable work on new elements (.live)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143905/making-jeditable-work-on-new-elements-live)

but neither have a perfect solution, but worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that's not pretty but it helps eliminate code duplication right now.

I just added this in my partial:

```
<!-- _item_info.html.erb -->
...
<li class="item-edit" id="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.name %> </li>
...
<% javascript_tag  do -%>
    $('.item-edit').editable('/item/update', {
        name  : $(this).attr('name'),
        id  : $(this).attr('id'),
        cancel  : 'Cancel',
        submit  : 'OK',
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip  : 'Click to edit...',
        method  :  'put',
        submitdata  :  {attribute : "name"}
    });
...
```

I no longer have to do any re-registration in my .js.erb files.

Comment: Yes, you could do that... or if you want to keep your javascript in your js.erb files, your update.js.erb could just find the most recent .item-edit node. If this node is appended at the end of the rest of the items, you could just index the array that you get from $('.item-edit') with its length - 1