# jeditable live()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When using live() and clicking text box while in edit mode the box expands as if the editable was binding each time you hover over it..how do you fix it?
thanks

```
$('.edit').live('click', function(){
    $('.edit').editable('folder_edit.php', {
        style: 'padding: 1px 2px 1px 3px',
        style: 'font-size: 12px',
        style: 'background-color: #ffffaa'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it chaging the class name to something else ie:
$('.edit').live('click', function(){

to

$('.editme').live('click', function(){

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you could have also done something like...

```
$('.edit').live('click', function(){
    $(this).editable('folder_edit.php', {
```